# Disable click for pending view of cwac-endless adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, cwac-endless

I am using [cwac-endless](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) adapter , and i am facing problems in disabling the click on the pending view while i try to load more results.

This is the constructor i am using for my custom adapter which extends EndlessAdapter. R.layout.pending which gets inflated while loading. I want to disable click on this list Item.

```
public class MyEndlessAdapter extends EndlessAdapter{
    public MyEndlessAdapter(Context context, ListAdapter wrapped, int pendingResource) {
        super(context, wrapped, R.layout.pending);
    }
}
```

R.layout.pending xml is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:text="Getting more results..."
/>
```

What i tried was to give android:clickable="false" for the TextView, but it din't work.

So, i would like to know if there are any work arounds for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My `ListView` is `lv`

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            EndlessWordAdapter a = (EndlessWordAdapter)
                parent.getAdapter();
            if(!(a.getItemViewType(position) == 
                Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE)) {
                // Do something
            } else {
                // Ignore, pending view was clicked
            }
        }
    });
```

Disabling long press works the same way.

Comment: could you please explain on the Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE

Comment: [Read this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE). I actually read [sources](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/blob/master/src/com/commonsware/cwac/endless/EndlessAdapter.java) of cwac-endless and noted `getItemViewType()` method. See how it works and how the author commented it.

Comment: I'm not shure, but I think `Adapter.IGNORE_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE` means "this view is in ListView but it is not active/enabled/works as other items".